# Databricks notebook - return all values from a table

Tags: sql, databricks

For test purposes, I have an empty DB into which I populate a tiny amount of data, extracted and transformed from a json file.

I would like to create a notebook using scala, which gets all values from all columns from a given table, and exit the notebook returning this result as a string.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
val result = spark.sql("select * from table.DB").as[String];
dbutils.notebook.exit(result)
```

However the first command fails with error:
AnalysisException: Try to map struct<Version:bigint,metadataInformation:struct<metadataID:string... etc ...> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;

However, something like the following works, to retrieve value of a specific field, from a column:

```
val result = spark.sql("select column.jsonfield from table.DB").as[String].first();
dbutils.notebook.exit(result)
```

How can I return the content of all columns?

Comment: How do you propose "all values from al columns from a table" to be squeezed into a single string? CSV? Fixed width? Straight up concatenated with nothing in between? Formatted as a nice table? There's a functional gap there that the code can't automatically close for you.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed, at this point, a straight up concatenated string would do, with a delineation between columns, if straight forward. The result will be obtained by a test harness that will parse this.

Comment: it's better not to do that way - there are limitations on the size of the data returned from notebook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val result = spark.sql("SELECT x FROM y").collect().toList.flatMap(x => x.toSeq).mkString(",")

dbutils.notebook.exit(result)
```